# C program for large file encryption/decryption using asymmetric keys

Tags: c++, c, openssl, embedded, embedded-linux

I am stuck on this problem where I need to do a encrypt-decrypt on a large file (>5MB) using asymmetric key with the help of OpenSSL.

Below is a brief description of my requirement:-

1. I have a device running with Linux on it.
2. The device can download a firmware image/patch from a server.
3. The image/patch in the server will be encrypted using a public key which will be already shared to them.
4. Once the image is downloaded, the device needs to verify its authenticity by decrypting it using the private key.
5. The target device will use OpenSSL libraries built and installed on it for decryption.
6. Along with this the target device needs to verify the signature of the firmware image/patch downloaded.

I have found a number of different ways of doing it on the Internet. The most appealing way to me is using `OpenSSL S/MIME encrypt/decrypt`. But I didn't find a suitable library/tool for doing this using C programming language. All the examples that I've found were mostly using a console application.

There were some sample C programs but those were not doing the encryption and decryption using asymmetric keys; they used a random 128 bit key and IV instead.

Could anyone please help me by providing some examples.

Comment: why not just a `fork` and an [exec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... Could you please elaborate a bit on this..

Comment: With `fork`, you can spawn other processes. The child process can then run an `exec` and turn the child process into a script which does what you want (that command line solution that you mentioned). In the meantime the parent process waits until the child process dies. Not the best practice in this case, but quite quick-n-dirty.

Comment: The device does not have the openSSL binaries. It only has the shared libraries. If it had the binaries then I could have done it with the Linux "System" API call or using the shell script. Now since it has got only shared libraries I need a way to translate this command line option to a C program. "openssl  smime -decrypt  -in  LargeFile_encrypted.zip  -binary -inform DEM -inkey privatekey.pem  -out  LargeFile.zip". I am looking for an equivalent of the above command in the C program. If you have any documentation for this then please let me know.

Comment: [jariq](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3325704/jariq) has already provided you with an answer about how [openssl smime works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28048687/4371276).

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget that OpenSSL is open-source. If you want to see the source code of "openssl smime" command than you need to take a look at [apps/smime.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/smime.c) file in openssl source code.